# Does Outlook 2010 show screentips and/or supertips for controls added to a contextMenu?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbonx

I am adding context menus in Outlook 2010. I am just testing with the following code. Am reading about these things [Extending the user Interface In Outlook 2010.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172%28v=office.14%29.aspx#OfficeOLExtendingUI_AttachmentContextMenu)

The button label is shown but no tips.

```
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuAttachments">
  <button id="MyContextMenuAttachments"
      label="ContextMenuAttachments"
          supertip="This is a super tip"
          screentip="This is a screentip"/>
</contextMenu>
```

I am also testing this with `idMso="ContextMenuMailItem"` as well and have the same problem.

Does Outlook show some form of tip for menu items? If yes how?

Update: Originally I did show an example of the attachments context menu, but I am interested in the `idMso="ContextMenuMailItem"` as well. Outlook does have some kind of tips for some menu items.  What kind of controls are these?  See added image.

[image: Outlook 2010 context menu with some tip]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Outlook show some form of tip for menu items? If yes how?

Yes, but not for context menu items/controls. I don't see such attributes in the Fluent UI schema for context menu controls. See [Office 2010 Reference: Office Fluent User Interface XML Schema](https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=1574) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. This might be a dumb question but where does that reference install to? I see ist an xsd file inside but what does the installer do?

Comment: Ok it looks like it installs it to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Xml\Schemas\1033 or I already had it there anyway.  Now I just need to understand it. And also understand why if my .xml file in Visual Studio points to this schema that it does not give a warning.

Comment: Hi, I know this is a fairly old post but is there a definitive solution to the question asked. The link for more information doesn't work anymore and I'm still unsure what controls allow other contextMenu items like the image above to display screentips and supertips

Comment: You can read about available ribbon controls and their possible children controls in the [Customize the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12)) when MSDN article comes back online.